# How to count the number of detected objects in the image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-segmentation

I want to develop an application that can count the number of objects in an image. It's not important to know the shape of the objects. I just need the information of how many objects in an image.

And I want to be able to implement it with many images. Is that possible? How to do that?

Here is my code:

```
    a=citra1;  
    a_citra_keabuan = rgb2gray(a);
    threshold = graythresh(a_citra_keabuan);
    a_bww = im2bw(a_citra_keabuan,threshold);
    a_bw = bwareaopen(a_bww,30);
    se = strel('disk',2);
    a_bw = imclose(a_bw,se);
    a_bw=~a_bww;
    [labeled,numObjects]=bwlabel(a_bw);
```

The `numObjects` shows the number of the detected objects in an images.

Here is the sample of the images

[Images1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoWAX.jpg)

[Images2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHhHy.jpg)

Comment: Much better this time!

Comment: Would it help to add edge detection, say prior to application of the threshold, to delimit regions more clearly? To work with many images, why not try a `for` loop?

Comment: what would you want the numObjects to be for each sample image? If you say anything >1, then you are asking for something pretty sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

To start off you can flood the images in different colors and thereafter detect how many colors are left. So basically take a point, fill its neighbors with the same color if some condition is satisfied. This should leave a picture with big fields (the before objects if the conditions are right). These can be counted then.

Here's a hint on how to do that:
http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/25/neighbor-indexing-2/